# How can I use docxtpl and pandas to fill a single Word file with rendered labels?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, docxtpl

I am using docxtpl and pandas to generate a Word document that contains multiple labels created using docxtpl.

I have an Excel file containing the data for the labels and a document with Jinja syntax. My goal is to generate a document that includes all the labels, one after another, with a page break between each label.

Here is the code snippet I have tried:

```
# Number of labels:
for i in range(len(excel_file)):
    # Content to add within the labels:
    context = {'NUMBER': number}
    template.render(context)
template.save("foo.docx")
```

However, this code only generates the last label. I also attempted to use the docx library, but I was unable to achieve the desired result.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue.

Comment: Can you provide sample images of what you're trying to create?